# What download managers are available for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, download-manager

> **This question exists as it fills a specific criterion.  While you are encouraged to help maintain its answers, please understand that "big list" questions are not generally allowed on Ask Ubuntu and will likely be closed per the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask). More information on the [software-recommendation tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1872/how-to-run-the-software-recommendation-tag).**

What download managers are available for Ubuntu? Can you provide the link as well?

Comment: type in terminal, `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tahutek-team/prozilla`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get install prozilla`.

Answer (score 82):

I would recommend the `wget` command line utility which is absolutely awesome!

`wget` is a GNU free software package that is used for retrieving files over the web. If you have got it installed, then all you have to do is to get the download link and use wget to download it.

In order to get the download link, right click on whichever download you want in the firefox download manager. There will be an option ‘copy download link’. Click on it.

Then open a terminal and go to whichever folder you want the file downloaded to. Assuming it is in the Desktop, type the following command at the prompt:

```
$ wget <paste your download link here>
```

Now even if it gets stuck in the middle, you can resume from wherever it was interrupted by giving the option `-c` to `wget`. That is, the command will be like

```
$ wget -c <paste your download link here>
```

And there it continues beautifully.

Comment: I would say Aria2 is a better solution for downloading via the command line. http://aria2.sourceforge.net

Comment: wget is not technically a download manager nor they identify themself as such.

Comment: This command also can't download resources that needs HTTP cookies, there is a workaround, sure, but who wants to type a command n times in a day? I don't.

Comment: @Ram The beauty of commandline programs is that they can be scripted, scheduled, triggered on events, etc. so you don't have to type the same thing over and over :)

Comment: @Warbo Sure, they are useful. As a developer I use them every day but `wget` is not a  download **manager**.  You can of course develop a GUI app on top of it, just like some suggested apps in this question's answers!

Answer (score 29):

**Axel** is great! There is no limit on the number of connections, and you can utilize your bandwidth.

To install axel use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install axel
```

It's a CLI application. So open a terminal window and type in `axel`
For more information and checking available options, you can look at the help page. I usually use these options:

```
axel -avn 50 address
```

It provides more information (`-v`), displays the alternative progress bar (`-a`) and downloads with 50 simultaneous connections (`-n 50`).

---

**Downthemall** extension for firefox is also great.

[image]

[Install it from here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/downthemall/ or search downthemall in the addon manager.)

Comment: Firefox has addons that are fast evolving. One of the best is Flashgot, which allows setting Axel as default or occasional (FlashGot Media) downloader.

Answer (score 26):

Try using [**FatRat download/upload manager**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fatrat/) , though a QT based but supports a lot of Features and is continuously extended.

Some of its features:

- HTTP(S)/FTP downloads
- FTP uploads
- Support for SOCKS5 and HTTP proxies
- RSS feed support + special functions for TV shows and podcasts
- BitTorrent support (including torrent creating, DHT, UPnP, encryption etc.)
- Torrent search on major torrent sites incl. The Pirate Bay, EZTV, BitTorrentMonster...
- RapidShare.com FREE and premium downloads
- RapidShare.com uploads
- RapidShare.com link verification and folder extraction
- RapidSafe link decoding
- MD4/MD5/SHA1 hash computing
- Remote control via Jabber (!)
- Remote control via an AJAX* web interface
- Subtitle search
- RAR/ZIP file unpacker
- Scheduler
- Clipboard monitor

You can even select the **Download Protocol client**, if supported as

[image]

On main Window , you can browse options like `Details, Transfer speed Graphs ,Queue speed Graphs and Logs.`

[image]

From settings window , you can setup **FatRat** for the following **services**

[image]

---

Other Useful Links :-

For [Browser Integration](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/browser-integration)

For [Plugins](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/plugins) and for [Extensions](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/plugin-structure)

For [FatRat Documentation](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/documentation)

[Official FatRat Page](http://fatrat.dolezel.info/)

Comment: installed it from synaptic and it would not start. any tweaks?

Comment: @cipricus - You mean cannot initialize  ?? , if already running try `fatrat -f` to bring it to front . Since it also provides No-Gui mode. Do comment back.:)

Comment: @cipricus - I didn't said No comment , i said **DO comment** :). Thanks for replying though . I guess it is because it based on QT library . In Lubuntu ( which i rarely) used doesn't include any component of QT library. You should go forward as  post the question as  eg. `How to make Fatrat run in Lubuntu ` inspite of being a QT application.

Comment: Is there any way that I can make it to shut down the computer after all download are finished ? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 23):

You can't download a file faster than what the speed of your connection allows. However as @llori pointed out **"It is not about going faster than your local connection, but about overriding download bandwidth per stream from the server itself. That's why it is an 'accelerator.'"** Thus it doesn't make your connection faster, but it lets you download faster from a server that doesn't allow you to do that.

## Gwget

[image]

Gwget is a download manager for the Gnome Desktop . The main features are: 
Resume: By default, gwget tries to continue any download.

---

- Notification: Gwget tries to use the
  Gnome notification area support, if
  available. You can close the main
  window and gwget runs in the
  background.
- Recursivity: Gwget detects when you
  put a html, php, asp or a web page
  dir in the url to download, and ask
  you to only download certain files
  (multimedia, only the index, and so
  on).
- Drag & Drop: You can d&d a url to the
  main gwget window or the notification
  area icon to add a new download.
- Firefox Extension: Fireget

Sources: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.com) & [GNOME.org](http://projects.gnome.org/gwget/)

Comment: It is not about going faster than your local connection, but about overriding download bandwidth per stream from the server itself. That's why it is an "accelerator".

Comment: i'll add that to my answer

Comment: @cipricus Gwget apparently was abandoned and the last available package is for Lucid, you can try to install it though I don't know if it works on current releases.

Answer (score 23):

There are plenty of them available.

### Steadyflow

Steadyflow is a simple and easy to use download manager, written in GTK. It has a lot of good features without any unnecessary complexity.

[image]

It also has an indicator applet.

[image]

**Install:** `sudo apt-get install steadyflow`

---

### Uget

**[uGet](http://uget.visuex.com/)** is a multi-platform GTK3 download manager that supports resuming downloads, comes with categories support, can download torrent and metalink files through aria2, a powerful command line download tool that's integrated into uGet.

[image]

**Install:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install uget aria2
```

---

### Jdownloader

**[JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/download/index)** is a free and open source cross platform (Linux,Mac ..) download manager, written in Java, which allows the automatic download of files and split files from one-click. Additionally, many “link encryption” sites are supported – so you just paste the “encrypted” links and JD does the rest.

[image]
**Install:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install jdownloader-installer
```

---

### Aria

Aria is not a GUI download manager, but it can be used via several Firefox extensions. Two of them are:

- [Flashgot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/)
- [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)

**Install:** `sudo apt-get install aria2`

---

### Gwget

**Gwget** is a gnome frontend for the popular downloading application wget. gwget also has firefox integration with the help of the firefox extension **[FireGet](http://gnome.org/projects/gwget/download.html)**. However, it is not updated since 2009.

[image]

---

#### More Information

[**Steadyflow**](http://linuxpoison.blogspot.in/2012/07/simple-download-manager-for-ubuntu.html)

[**Uget**](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/uget-download-manager-110-released-with.html)

[**Jdownloader**](http://www.linoob.com/2010/08/best-ubuntu-download-managers-reviewed/)

Comment: These should've been split to several answers.

Comment: 1+ for uGet, the rest is silence.

Answer (score 12):

No one can beat **Aria2**, Best Downloader  I have seen ever. It can resume your download after several months, even from Mediafire. The Only drawback is - its a command line tool. But don't be afraid, it is quite easy to use. It also integrates with uGet as a plugin so you can use [uGet](http://ugetdm.com/) as a GUI for aria2.

Install it with the command

```
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

---

[image]

You can also install Flashgot addon on Firefox, and set aria2 as Flashgot default downloader. That way, whenever you click to download something, flashgot will automatically download it with aria2.

Comment: I think, resuming support is website specific and As far as I know, mediafire support resuming option by default. That is why Aria2 can resume. If the site doesn't have resuming option, you can't resume, even with the best Download manager of the time.

Comment: Why several answers recommending uGet?

Answer (score 11):

Do you mean a download manager for ubuntu 10.10?

If so, i prefer jDownloader.
[jDownloader on PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jd-team/+archive/jdownloader)

[image]

There you also can see how to install it.

- [what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

Comment: SO, what are the features of this? Why should I use it?

Answer (score 10):

[Flareget](http://flareget.com) is probably the best download manager available for Linux (quoting from softpedia.com) It is highly stable and has almost [all the features](http://flareget.com/features) you can think of. It is multi-threaded and supports upto 16 segments per download for download acceleration. It has inbuilt browser integration and YouTube video download support for all the browsers. It is also actively maintained and a pro version is also available.

**This is not free software. Limitation of free version: only 2 segments per download of files larger than 25 MB.** (as of v. 3.2.42 in 2014)

[image]

Comment: it should be noted that to get the 16 connections, browser integration and many other features that you will have to buy the "Pro" version as the free version does not offer these features.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell Only 16 connection feature is restricted rest everything is free including browser integration.

Comment: since when? the browser integration was the first thing that was limited...then they added on more and more limitations.

Comment: @MichaelTunnell Since last 3 months, you better keep your self updated before commenting on any post

Comment: that is absurd thing to say...the flareget site doesnt mention the differences anywhere you have to test the app first to find the limitations...saying people should use the app to see what the limitations are is absurd, there should be a Community vs Pro comparison page. I would never be wrong about it if it was made easier to know the differences.

Comment: the free version of Flareget has only 2 connections per download of a file larger than 25 MB

Comment: the free version doesn't qualify at all anymore, and the payed version is surpassed by competition.

Answer (score 9):

Axel is the true Download accelerator for Ubuntu. It is a command-line based tool (which comes with a gui version which starts the download in a terminal window).

To instal : `sudo apt-get install axel axel-kapt`

Axel-kapt is the gui-version.

Downloading via axel is as simple as typing `axel url` on a terminal. Useful flags include :

- -n to control number of simultaneous threads.
- -a for a much simpler download progress bar (akin to wget)
- -o to specify an output file

You can install [Download Helper extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfjkgbjaikamkkojmakjclmkianficch) in Chrome (which allows axel to take over downloads in chrome).

In Firefox it can be easily used with [FlashGot addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/flashgot/) as  alternative to the default downloader.

[image]

[image]
I also use it with [plowdown](http://code.google.com/p/plowshare/) as an alternative to jdownloader (automatically downloads files from various websites, automating the browser)

Answer (score 9):

I still prefer to use `wget` on files.

Or you can try [`plowshare`](http://code.google.com/p/plowshare/) which is a command-line tool:

[image: plowshare]

Answer (score 9):

## [UGet](http://ugetdm.com/)

The program `uGet` is available in the repositories and is an excellent download manager with many useful options. As you can see in the screenshot below, it can pause a large download and resume it successfully (if the server supports resuming). I have used it with great success to download large and small files alike.

You can also queue and classify downloads and allow it to monitor the clipboard for potential downloads. Bandwidth can be controlled per download or on a global scale and, if necessary, you can specify a proxy to use. When `flashgot` is installed in firefox, `uGet` can be chosen as the default download manager for that browser.

uGet in action with a large file partially downloaded and paused:
[image: :]

To boost speed by using multi-thread downloads, enable area2 plugin:

[image]

Comment: @cipricus By default probably not, but there is an option to specify the number of connections to use, although the number you can get will depend on the server to which you are connecting.

Comment: uGet utilizes both Aria2 and CURL as a backend. Enabling the Aria2 Plugin activates the multi-connection, source, etc features that are not there by default. (both uGet and Aria2 are free so enabling the plugin doesn't have any caveats)

Comment: Why more uGets?

Answer (score 7):

You should try [steadyflow](http://packages.ubuntu.com/steadyflow) [image: Install steadyflow]  It seems quite good. and it integrates with unity. Do you see the `cloud` icon with the blue arrow in the top bar?

[image]

If you want to integrate it with Firefox, try the [Flashgot](http://flashgot.net) plugin. For Chrome(-ium), use [Chromeflow](https://launchpad.net/chromeflow).

Comment: Steady flow is good, but are you sure I can download 600 MB fedora using it ? Dont suggest me about the torrent.

Comment: I believe you should be able to. Don't see any reason why not.

Answer (score 6):

**KGet** is an awesome download manager. It's built for KDE, but supports HTTP[S], FTP, BitTorrent, MetaLink and combinations of all those things, as well as multi-threading, etc. It's cross-platform too.

[DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/downthemall/) Firefox addon is great too.

Usually I use it. It doesn't support BitTorrent, though, but I use `Transmission` for that.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Even if i have no problems downloading big files with any downloader (maybe there is something wrong with your filesystem or internet connection) I can recommend the [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/downthemall/) - Addon for Firefox

But maybe you can explain what you mean by "...none of them work..."

Comment: @oZRiz: Yes the problem is I have only 30 KBPS Connection and therefore I need to download a file (Over 1GB) part by part.

Answer (score 5):

I use Uget. Its a simple downloader, and supports resuming. THe latest version of uGet ie v1.8.0 also supports torrents. when you run uGet, it also does very well to detect the presence of a filepath in the clipboard, and asks if you want to start downloading.

[image]

Comment: uGet is one of the very few download managers with metalink support.

Answer (score 5):

That product appears to be snakeoil.  A download is a download; there is no magical incantation to make it go "5 times faster".  The partial exception to this is when you are downloading from a site with multiple mirrors, then you can download from all of them simultaneously like the program `axel` does.  This really only helps though if you have unlimited bandwidth and the mirrors are the bottleneck, and this is rarely the case.

Comment: NEW ONE: http://askubuntu.com/questions/259228/alternative-to-internet-download-manager-6-x-x-for-ubuntu

Comment: It's not snakeoil - IDM will begin downloading the file at 5 (or more) starting points in each request.  That will keep 5 open connections running.  It's especially useful for video downloads where the videos are meant to be streamed and the outbound bandwidth is throttled per request.  But if outbound bandwidth is not throttled, then this technique has minimal impact.

Answer (score 5):

While I agree that this is complete nonsense (most sites don't trickle their connections to limit per-connection bandwidth caps, these days), of course there are download managers.

Possibly the most popular cross-platform application is [DownloadThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/). It's a plugin for Firefox.

Answer (score 5):

### jDownloader

#### Pros

- It can **download from many file sharing site**.
- Its built-in link **grabber makes it better at getting links**.
- It can be used to **download from firefox** with extension [Flashgot](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/&ei=-4rFT5OiOZHKrAfrpZCuBQ&usg=AFQjCNFBVxk_bjb0m9PBzEb6WLAqtjrDmA&sig2=MPyj3Hxm17j-rVnAynGbPQ)
- It has anti-capcha capability.
- Fantastic resume capability.
- Active team of developers

#### Cons

- Developed in java and `JVM` is resource intensive some times. (same problem with Azureus or Vuze though in my opinion)
- Complex GUI.

I used `IDM` on Windows long ago and I was missing a downloader like `IDM` and found `jDownloader`. you will need some time to get used to jDownloader

I have downloaded files greater than 2-3 GB with many disconnections (due to network problem) but the `MD5` was exact !

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately **IDM** is not available for Ubuntu/Linux but there are many utilities are available which can give you fastest speed like [**wget**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wget.1.html) and [**Axel**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/axel.1.html) are powerful download utilities.

to install it

```
sudo apt-get install wget axel
```

you may get confused how to use them in easy way. I have a nice technique which I usually do.

Type in terminal

```
Wget -c  '<link>'.

axel '<Link>'
```

Here link can be retrieved from firefox's download window .Begin Downloading any file from firefox . It will appear in firefox download box.  Pause the download process. Right click on downloading file. Choose **"Copy Link location"**

Paste it in terminal in place of link. Here note that you should not missed single quote. If you want to stop then press **CTRL+C** best thing is that your download would never be corrupted and you can resume it by pressing **Up** key and enter( command again).

Comment: Fortunately it is! http://askubuntu.com/questions/259228/alternative-to-internet-download-manager-6-x-x-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

Firefox extension *DownThemAll* with parallel download and resume support.

Answer (score 4):

I use jdownloader. 
It's a very good download manager which even supports various one click file hosters like rapidshare, fileserve etc.

You can download it from [here](http://jdownloader.org/download/index).

Answer (score 4):

I humbly recommend TwistLoad for managing downloads. The program provides the core functionality you would expect in a download manager: automatically following redirects, cross-session interrupt / resume support, and a nice GUI interface to keep track of everything:

[image]

You can download TwistLoad from my PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~george-edison55/+archive/george-edison).

**Disclaimer:** I am the author.

Comment: [Which one](http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/)?

Answer (score 4):

I think that JDownloader can do everything that you want:

- Download online streaming video/audio: included by default
- [Scheduling](http://jdownloader.org/home/addons#jd-scheduler)
- Grab links from the website: included by default
- [Integration for chrome](http://jdownloader.org/news/blog/x20110429-140644chrome#jdownloader-integration-for-google-chrome)

Comment: thanks for the answer, it helps me too. Anyway, what type of jDownloader installation that you prefer? Using the PPA or download the .sh installer from the jDownloader site? Did the jDownloader support the function like "shutdown on complete"? Thanks for the answer :D

Comment: Glad to help :)
I prefer using the PPA, I think it is easier and keeps it updated.
I never tried the "shutdown on complete" but there's an addon for that: http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/addons/list/jdshutdown

Comment: Will the integration with browsers also work?

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDownloader) this software is "Mostly GNU General Public License but partly closed-source". Thus, it's not wholly free.

Comment: I installed JD and integrated fith Firefox using Flashgot. But, whenever i am trying to download videos from Youtube, JD shows the download list as 'videoplayback'(not its original name). Also, i cannot download another video because it is also named 'videoplayback' to JD. I already selected option auto rename from settings.

Answer (score 4):

Hello from the **uGet** project team,

I would suggest [**uGet**](http://ugetdm.com).

**uGet** is one of the most powerful download managers for Linux while still being very lightweight. Our latest version was released 10 days ago. (Sep. 9th, 2012)

**Steadyflow** is a great program but is very limited in features as it was designed to be because of being for minimalists.

**JDownloader** is Java based so it is not going to be the best when it comes to resource management.

**MultiGet** had potential but its current version is an Alpha stage and has not been updated since 2010.

Answer (score 4):

## Flareget

Is the most Versatile Download Manager I found.

It is having all most all the features of popular download managers like IDM or DAP

> *** Batch Download * Browser Integration * Scheduled Download**
>
> *** Flash Video Downloading**

All those features are there.

[image]

[image]

Installation:

- Latest release can be downloaded from [flareget.com](http://flareget.com/download)
- Upto Ubuntu 13.10: can be installed with following commands;

*For 32 bit:*

```
cd ~/Downloads && sudo wget -c "http://www.flareget.com/files/flareget/debs/i386/flareget_2.3-24_i386(stable)_deb.tar.gz" && tar xzvf 'flareget_2.3-24_i386(stable)_deb.tar.gz' && cd 'flareget_2.3-24_i386(stable)_deb' &&  sudo dpkg -i flareget_2.3-24_i386.deb
```

*For 64 bit:*

```
cd ~/Downloads && sudo wget -c "http://www.flareget.com/files/flareget/debs/amd64/flareget_2.3-24_amd64(stable)_deb.tar.gz" && tar xzvf 'flareget_2.3-24_amd64(stable)_deb.tar.gz' && cd 'flareget_2.3-24_amd64(stable)_deb' &&  sudo dpkg -i flareget_2.3-24_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `axel` download manager. It is a command line tool but It support downloading files part by part, which is a popular method of accelerated download. The manual page of axel is saying this:

> Axel  is  a  program  that  downloads  a file from a FTP or HTTP server
>      through multiple connection, each connection downloads its own part  of
>      the file.

<sup>source: [manual page for Axel](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/axel.1.html)</sup>

You can also explicitly mention the number of part it should do to accelerate download.
The options of axel is as follows:

```
Usage: axel [options] url1 [url2] [url...]

--max-speed=x       -s x    Specify maximum speed (bytes per second)
--num-connections=x -n x    Specify maximum number of connections
--output=f      -o f    Specify local output file
--search[=x]        -S [x]  Search for mirrors and download from x servers
--header=x      -H x    Add header string
--user-agent=x      -U x    Set user agent
--no-proxy      -N  Just don't use any proxy server
--quiet         -q  Leave stdout alone
--verbose       -v  More status information
--alternate     -a  Alternate progress indicator
--help          -h  This information
--version       -V  Version information
```

Try this download manager. You'll be satisfied with this.

> I want a perfect alternative of Orbit Downloader or Internet Download Manager of Windows

This can be a perfect replacement of Internet Download Manager. I tried downloading same file using `wget` and `axel`. The speed in `axel` outperforms wget very easily.

**What I recommend from the three**: If you want me to select a download manager from your list in the question, I would select **JDownloader** for it's feature richness. Though It requires [Java](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Java) to be run.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend QuickDownloader.

> QuickDownloader is a download manager that accelerates downloads by
>   between 200-300%.
>
> It provides a resume capability for resuming broken downloads. It
>   supports both HTTP and FTP downloads.
>
> Here are some key features of QuickDownloader:
>
> - Support for multiple Downloads
> - System Integrity Checkers which ensure that all system critical
> - components exists and are in the correct location
> - Memory use reduced to between 2-4mb
> - Capability to carry out both downloads and Resume simultaneously
> - Extensive Decoupling of Code to reduce dependencies between code    which could cause problem in future
> - Better Handling of errors
> - Information on each Download that can be resumed
> - Buffer Resizing for optimum use
> - Proxy Configuration for systems behind firewalls
> - Support for all types of Network connections such as Dial Up,    Broadband T1 etc.
> - Ability to download from both HTTP and FTP sites
> - 100 % Resume support on all downloads even if the server doesn't    support it.
> - Uses Java JRE which runs on any machine such as Windows 2000, 98,    Linux etc.
>     <sup>1</sup>

To download [Click Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qdown/files/downloads/5.0/LinuxInstaller.bin/download)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Linux Softpedia](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Internet/HTTP-WWW-/QuickDownloader-834.shtml)</sup>

[image]

Comment: how to install it? it has downloaded as a bin file called LinuxInstaller

Answer (score 3):

You can try out **flareGet** ( a recently released download manager for linux). It is multi-threaded and supports upto 16 segments per download for download acceleration. It supports browser integration for all the browsers - firefox, chrome, opera etc.
http://flareget.com/download

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While Uri Herrera had a very good explanation for what a download accelerator is, the solution that was pointed out, Gwget, is far from what he described as a download accelerator. Gwget is exactly what its name implies, a GUI on top of wget, the most basic of basic unix download program.

One of the reliable ways to get the job (acceleration) done is to download through multiple threads from a particular server. Some servers restrict download speed by threads, instead of the IP. In such cases, if a server limits your download to 100KB/s, having 6 thread will give you an upper bound of 600KB/s, a very significant boost.

So far the one linux program that does this is Multiget, it's a little bit of a pain to setup with firefox, however. But at least it's easy to install on Ubuntu. Google "Multiget deb" to download the debian package. Then look up on the [Multiget documentation](http://multiget.sourceforge.net/docs.html) to see how to hook it up with flashgot. Good Luck

Answer (score 3):

There are several download manager in Linux world but i preferred the following ones:

- **JDownloader**: Most powerful download manager in Linux (in my opinion). Using it you can start, stop or pause downloads, set bandwith limitations, auto-extract archives and much [more](http://jdownloader.org/).
- **MultiGet**: It is simple cross platform (Windows/Linux/BSDs/MacOS) download manager. It supports resuming downloads and SOCKS 4,4a,5 proxy, ftp proxy, http proxy. [More information](http://multiget.sourceforge.net/).
- **uGet**: It is simple and lightweight and has several good feature like, "Resume downloads", "Queue downloads", "Firefox integration", "Clipboard monitoring" and more. - http://ugetdm.com

Answer (score 2):

One download manager available you might want to take a look at is Steadyflow Download Manager.  Steadyflow works as a Unity indicator applet so to speak.

- A basic GNOME download manager, supporting all URL protocols known by GIO/GVFS. This includes, among others, HTTP, HTTPS, FTP and SMB.
- Pausing, resuming, and restarting downloads upon application restart.
- An application indicator, or a notification area icon for platforms without Ayatana libraries.
- An instant search/filter box.
- Ability to add downloads via the command line and D-Bus, for browser extension writers.
- Notification bubbles upon starting and finishing downloads (can be disabled).

To get Steadyflow, open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and issue the following comands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sikon/steadyflow
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install steadyflow
```

Comment: That mentioned [PPA](http://ppa.launchpad.net/sikon/steadyflow/ubuntu/dists) does not work for Trusty, currently!

Answer (score 2):

[Polipo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/polipo) is a local proxy that will sit between your browser and the internet and manage the connections. It is bundled with Tor setups as a way of avoiding the use of a socks proxy but maybe it can be used to optimize your internet connection, if you are technically inclined. If you do use it, it will likely be useful to enable pipelining and proxy pipelining in the Firefox registry (about:config) which will allow multiple connection requests to the server. You can then try to increase the maximum number of requests to 10 or so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/download/index).

It downloads almost from every sites, even from that that ask for captcha. It also boosts download speed if you rise "Max. Con." option.

PS: You can use [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/unity-integration-for-jdownloader-shows-speed-progress-on-unity-launcher/) site to install JDownloader from a ppa and have unity integration

Answer (score 2):

The best download managers for Ubuntu 12.04 are suggested above by other users since the IDM is not available for Ubuntu. If you are looking to download youtube or flash videos from any other sites you should install 'flashgot' add-on for Mozilla Firefox. You can get 'Flashgot add-on from the firefox add-on search page. For your information 'Flashgot' is also used as a site grabber like IDM. So you don't need to worry about not having IDM for your ubuntu.
I use Uget download manager and Flashon add-on for Mozilla firefox which works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

You can try out [flareGet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flareget/) (a recently released download manager for Linux). It is still in the beta stage but works pretty good. It is multi-threaded and supports up to 32 segments per download for download acceleration. For browser integration you can use flashgot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firefox you can use [downthemall](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) plugin also.

Answer (score 2):

[Aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/)

**Description:** (copied from the website on Nov 2013)

> aria2 is a light-weight multi-protocol & multi-source download utility
>   operated in command-line. The supported protocols are HTTP(S), FTP,
>   BitTorrent (DHT, PEX, MSE/PE), and Metalink.
>
> aria2 can download a file from multiple sources/protocols and tries to
>   utilize your maximum download bandwidth. It supports downloading a
>   file from HTTP(S)/FTP and BitTorrent at the same time, while the data
>   downloaded from HTTP(S)/FTP is uploaded to the BitTorrent swarm. Using
>   Metalink's chunk checksums, aria2 automatically validates chunks of
>   data while downloading a file like BitTorrent.
>
> ***There are other alternatives, such as wget and curl, but aria2 has two distinctive features***: (1) aria2 can download a file from
>   several URIs(HTTP(S)/FTP/BitTorrent) and (2) If you give aria2 a list
>   of URIs, aria2 downloads them concurrently. You don't have to wait for
>   the current download queue to finish one file at a time anymore. aria2
>   tries to utilize your maximum download bandwidth and downloads files
>   quickly.
>
> There are also some applications that have the ability to do segmented
>   downloading. Typically these applications split a file up by the
>   number of threads and download them in parallel and wait for all
>   threads to finish. In other words, they don't split unfinished
>   segments adaptively. Normally, if things go well, this strategy works
>   well, but if one thread is very slow (i.e. one of the server is very
>   slow), then you have to wait for it to finish. aria2 can cope with
>   this peculiar situation. aria2 can split segments adaptively all the
>   way down to 1MiB. So you don't have to worry about the above problem.
>   But you might complain: if a slow server is downloading at 1MiB, then
>   one has to wait for that none the less. The answer is "no". Even in
>   such a case, aria2 does the job quite well: aria2 cancels slow servers
>   and use the faster server to finish the download. In other words,
>   ***aria2 is very clever and reliable in many situations***.
>
> Unlike the original Aria, which has a GTK+ interface, aria2 provides
>   only a command-line interface. And as a result, it has lower resource
>   requirement. The physical memory usage is typically 4MiB (normal
>   HTTP/FTP downloads) to 9MiB (BitTorrent downloads). CPU usage in
>   BitTorrent with download speed of 2.8MiB/sec is around 6%.

Comment: What are you saying? My post starts with the reference link.

Answer (score 2):

`wget` is **not** a download manager, it is a download **utility**. By **default** you cannot do these things

- You can't pause downloads
- You can't view history
- You can't schedule downloads
- You can't download multiple files **at the same time**
- You can't download multiple files **from 2 different URLs**
- You can't restart downloads

When you have all these things in one utility, then you're allowed to call it a manager. For example Calibre is an ebook manager. Just because Adobe reader reads PDF, it doesn't make it a manager. Wget is no better than Curl for downloading stuff, hell I find Curl much more useful, at least you can use it in programming.

Some geek might leave a comment, you can do all that if you edit `.bashrc` or write a bash command or something. A download manager should do all these things **easily** and by **default**. I could browse the web in Emacs, if I download a plugin or write a script, that does not make Emacs itself a web browser.

To answer the question, I personally use Uget, but many people mentioned it so I'll mention [pyLoad](http://pyload.org/) which is another great downloader.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, and I don't entirely agree either, so I will just say this. What features define or don't define a *Download Manager* is a matter of debate (not fitting on this site). I don't think there is an authoritative definition. For instance, if you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Download_manager, scroll to the very bottom and click on [Show] in the *Download Managers* box, you will see `wget` listed there, along with many other applications which do not all support all the features that you request of a download manager. And yet, people call them so.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa this is inevitably what we will get with that kind of question. I personally think that the question is the main problem here, not the answer.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I understand your point, and you do have a point, but even `wget` team does not seem to call it a manager, this is the main site http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ and this is the wiki page for Wget http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget they don't call it manager, it's not even here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers

Comment: @Braiam I totally agree with you, there was a discussion on area51 to create a software recommendation site on SE, everyone admired the idea but it didn't make it because they thought it would create problems

Comment: Please @MalteSkoruppa and Fischer further discussions drop it in [meta]

Answer (score 2):

I use `aria2` which is a terminal based download manager utility.
If you like UI then go for uGet.

[This article](http://www.crappy3.com/get-free-download-manager-ubuntu/) might help you decide which one to install and help with installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `prozilla` with this by opening a terminal and typing:

```
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/prozilla/prozilla_1.3.6-9_i386.deb 
sudo dpkg -i prozilla_1.3.6-9_i386.deb
```

I also like kget, uget and fatrat.

kget is pre-installed on kde-plasma but if you wanna get it with Ubuntu desktop  then you can with

```
sudo apt-get install kget
```

In the same way you can install uget and fatrat, for example

```
sudo apt-get install fatrat
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a review of [***Best 8 Download Managers/Accelerators for Linux***](http://www.linuxb.in/2012/01/best-8-download-managersaccelerators.html)

**Prozilla**, which is rated as No.1 there, also has a GUI although it doesn't look very modern:

**ProzGUI** can be installed by entering these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alza/project
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prozgui
```

**Prozilla + Zenity**

Those who would like a **GUI** and a really really fast and powerful **Download Accelerator** such as **Prozilla** but don't like **prozgui** due to its very outdated looks, numerous small windows, etc., can simply use a basic **zenity-powered script** like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
URL=`zenity --title='URL to Download' --text='Please enter URL of the file to be downloaded to ~/Downloads' --entry`
xterm -fa "Ubuntu Mono:size=10" -title 'Prozilla Downloading...' -e "proz -r -f --no-search --directory-prefix=/home/$USER/Downloads "$URL"" &
```

Some options which can be added/modified:

```
-k=n              Use n connections instead of the default(4)
--no-search       Do a direct download (no ftpsearch)
--ftpsearch       Do a ftpsearch for faster mirrors
--min-size=n      If a file is smaller than 'n'Kb, don't search, just download it
```

Of course you need to install **prozilla**, **zenity** and **xterm** as below before running this script:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tahutek-team/prozilla
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install prozilla xterm zenity
```

Further information about installing non-GUI version of Prozilla can be found here:

- [Prozilla can now be installed on Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2013/04/prozilla-now-can-be-installed-on-ubuntu.html)
- [Fix dpkg error](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/12/fix-dpkg-error-dpkg-error-processing.html)

### ProZilla Kaptain Launcher

And for those who would like a good-looking GUI launcher including more options:

[Prozilla Kaptain Launcher](http://gnomefiles.org/content/show.php/Prozilla+Kaptain+Launcher?content=162866)

[image]

Comment: The question is not outdated, this answer IS.

Answer (score 1):

### Xtreme Download Manager

This question will not get outdated very soon, but most of the answers here are outdated. Beside uGet, few other applications mentioned thereunder are still alive. The best these days is probably XDG.

*It can get the download link for multimedia and download the file with multi-fragment acceleration.*

FROM   OFFICIAL   WEBSITE
http://xdman.sourceforge.net/

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/

""""
Features

***  Download any streaming video

XDM can download video and audio files from popular sites like YouTube, MySpaceTV, Google Video and many others. It is maybe the best way of downloading webpage embedded videos and such. "Download This Video" button pops up in most cases you are watching a video on the Internet. Just click on the button to start downloading clips.

[image]

***  Download 32 time faster (but you don't need that, let's be reasonable)

XDM can accelerate downloads by up to 32 times due to its intelligent dynamic file segmentation technology. XDM segments downloaded files dynamically during download process and reuses available connections without additional connect and login stages to achieve best acceleration performance.

[image]

****  Works with all browsers!

[image]

"""

for your ubuntu

Linux 64 bit:

$wget   https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/files/xdm-2018-x64.tar.xz/download

Linux 32 bit:

$wget  https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdman/files/xdm-2018-x86.tar.xz/download

$tar -xvf  yourFile.xz

--------------------------------/

```
FROM README FILE:
```

Installation instruction

1. Open terminal
2. Switch to the directory where you have extracted tar compressed file, there should be a file named install.sh
3. Execute the file as root. 
   a. In Ubuntu/Mint/Elementary OS or other Debian based Linux, use: sudo ./install.sh
4. If installation is successfull, you can start xdm from Start Menu or by typing xdman interminal as non root user
5. To uninstall run /opt/xdman/uninstall.sh as root

--------------------------------/
NB :

Pre-requisites : None

```
    ENJOY  !!!
```

Comment: While it is unique in its ability to get various multimedia source links, sometimes, with some multimedia sources it will report lost/reset connection, but copying the link into uGet or other downloader would result in successful download.

Answer (score 0):

Use [prozgui](http://ubuntuportal.com/2011/11/prozgui-fastest-download-accelerator-on-ubuntu-11-10.html)

I know download accelerators use multi thread type processes to achieve faster download speeds and from this I just found the ninja download accelerator for Ubuntu.

Yesterday my download took about 4 hours and still not complete for 2 GB and then failed.

Now Today I am using prozgui which I just downloaded and then in the preferences I updated the connections limit to 10 threads, currently I am at 15% of the download in under 3 min this product is unbelievably fast (the best)

Prozgui allows you to select the number of connection threads which allows you to use your full connection without no limits. I now have 10 threads downloading my file

And by the time I finished writing this message the download is already at 40%

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and it works perfectly fine

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Blatantly OUTDATED.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers here are outdated. But not those about [XDM](http://xdman.sourceforge.net/https://) and [uGet](https://ugetdm.com/). — With these two I don't need others, but one that is working fairly easily as I speak is worth mentioning: [AWGG(aka Advanced Wget GUI)](https://www.videohelp.com/software/AWGG)

Download the 0.6 version - the older ones are outdated - and run the executable — it's "portable". It is very similar to IDM of Windows, a lot of settings.

[image]

[image]

It states it has browser integration with the *Download with Wget* addon (for Firefox, [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/download-with-gnu-wget/)).

[image]

But I don't see that integration, as the context menu that addon brings will take the download to a terminal wget download (not the AWGG). The link (captured with other tool, probably XDM) can be copied and pasted (after selecting "+" New download), or can be dragged & dropped onto a "drop box" floating button. It doesn't have a "download" button like XDM and IDM, but has clipboard monitoring (just like uGet). Also, only aria2 tool if selected seems to provide multi-source download, and that limited to 5, which results in somewhat lower speeds than the competition aforementioned.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I like [Flashget](http://down6.flashget.com/flashget196en.exe) alot. Although it is only available for Windows but it runs fine with Wine and I use it for all my video/audio/torrent download tasks. You should give it a try. There are 2 versions of flashget available from their site. I would recommend that you use 1.9.6 instead of 3.3. Download speeds of both versions is same but 1.9.6 has a simple and less cluttered interface.
You can install Wine with command

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

After Wine is installed, download flashget196en.exe from flashget.com and install it. Then you can run Flashget from Wine programs.

Answer (score -1):

FlashGot firefox extension has an option to use DownThemAll Turbo (abbreviated to DTA Turbo there) as a downloader. It's a fastest Linux downloader I've ever used.

Answer (score -1):

uGet is a great solution and is the closest linux/ubuntu app to IDM available.

http://uget.visuex.com

Disclaimer: I may be a bit biased as I am a uGet project member.

Answer (score -2):

Try [Flashget](http://www.flashget.com/en/download.html) with Wine. I have been using it on Windows and Ubuntu (with wine) and its an excellent application. If you decide to give it a try, I would suggest installing version 1.9.6

Comment: Nah ! I hate flashget. I used it on windows and found it less satisfactory than Orbit. (Orbit is also free).

Comment: @CuriousApprentice Have you tried installing Orbit with Wine on Ubuntu?

Comment: Flashget also has a "call home" problem with sending user data to the Flashget servers as well as a lot of built-in adware.