# Good Download Manager for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone recommend a download manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager)

Can you recommand any download manager for Ubuntu?

Features I'm looking for:

- Works in Unity env.
- Can download from rapidshare.
- Supports sceduled downloads.

There is Transmission BitTorrent Client installed by default, but it supports only torrent downloads and have no scheduling support.

Answer (score 11):

[**Jdownloader**](http://jdownloader.org/home/index)

> JDownloader is open source, platform
>   independent, and written completely in
>   Java. It simplifies downloading files
>   from One-Click-Hosters like
>   Rapidshare.com or Megaupload.com - not
>   only for users with a premium account
>   but also for users who don't pay.

**Here are really cool things about jdwonloader:**

1. Completely Automates downloading
2. Scheduling downloads:  a rather nifty option whereby you can tell the program to, say, start downloading at 2 am in the morning or something like that.
3. Re-connects to defeat compulsory wait times
4. Supports a wide range of hosting services (and video sharing sites)
5. Captures multiple links on a webpage
6. Firefox integration: through the Flashgot Firefox extension. Jdownloader will provide the option to install this extension during its own installation process.

**Installation**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jdownloader
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**[uGet](http://urlget.sourceforge.net/)** is great.

> Uget (formerly urlgfe) is a Free and Open Source download manager written in GTK+ , it has many of features like easy-to-use , cross-platform (Windows & GNU/Linux) , support pause and resume , classify download , every category has an independent configuration , and...

Some new features in new version as uGet homepage says:

> What’s new since 1.6:
>
> 1. support for Torrent and Metalink file (with aria2 plug-in).
> 2. support for application indicator.
> 3. It can do speed limit control per download.
> 4. It can sort downloads by column in “All” category.
> 5. add scheduler.
> 6. add new plug-in that support aria2 version >= 1.10.
> 7. add new timestamp columns – “Added On” and “Completed On”.
> 8. add configure option “–with-gtk3″ to enable GTK+3 support.
> 9. add Belarusian translation file (Mihas Varantsou)
> 10. move web site from http://urlget.sourceforge.net/ to http://uget.visuex.com/

[image]

Install it using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:plushuang-tw/uget-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install uget
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I have installed it without addig repo or updating, bt simple from software centre. Downloading from rapidshare fails, don't know why :|

Comment: Also, I don't see option for scheduled downloads?

Comment: Rapidshare download works for me but I couldn't find scheduling options although the homepage says it's supported.Sorry.

Comment: I have tried. After I start download, it says it is finished already (rapidshare). Any idea?

Comment: Did you enter your username and password for rapidshare?

Answer (score 4):

**[Steadyflow 0.1.7](https://launchpad.net/steadyflow)**

> Steadyflow is an easy to use download manager for Ubuntu. The application is currently available for Ubuntu 11.04 "Natty Narwhal".With the latest release, Steadyflow has got some new features which makes it a very good option if you are looking for a download manager.

**Highlights:**

> • The indicator menu has been expanded and now includes download controls for individual files and for all files at once.
>
> • Password authentication is now supported for FTP, SFTP, SMB and so on.
>
> • It is now possible to select multiple files to start, stop, or remove them all at once. In addition, a file’s context menu now includes a “copy URL” option.
>
> • If Steadyflow is on the Unity dock, its icon’s context menu will include an “Add download” item.

[image]

**To install, run these codes in a terminal:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sikon/steadyflow

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install steadyflow
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Does it support scheduled downloads? Can it download files from rapidshare?

Comment: Sorry , It doesn't support scheduled downloads. But downloading from rapidshare is working for me.

Comment: OK, then it is out of the race. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I have tried. After I start download, it says it is finished already (rapidshare). Any idea?

Comment: @umpirsky: You know,because Rapidshare isn't free. When you want to get a direct link to download from it you need to have a premium account. When you have done this you can copy that direct link and add it to the download manager.

Comment: But you can download even with non free account, you just need to wait for 5 minutes or sth like that.

Comment: Yes sure, but no support for direct downloads, I mean when you copy and then add the link manually somehow they block the file to something else .cg something.So you must do a click only to download. (At first above I thought it worked)..

Comment: It's not available for Trusty, currently:  http://ppa.launchpad.net/sikon/steadyflow/ubuntu/dists