# What is the best downloading program for ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, internet, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Download Manager for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47628/good-download-manager-for-ubuntu)

I want to know the best downloading program for ubuntu, like IDM(Internet Download Manager) on windows and have the features of IDM .

Answer (score 6):

There are a few good graphical download managers, i'll give you a run by some of my favorite:

1. [**ProzGui**](http://prozgui.en.malavida.com/linux/) - Provides the user with a windows environment that allows to manage the ProZilla download manager with greater ease. This comes in very handy to accelerate the speed of our download, because it uses a technique that consists in dividing the files in various parts to be able to download them simultaneously from various servers.
2. **KGet** - If you use KDE this comes installed by default.
3. **Downloader for X (d4x)**

   Downloader for X is a powerful graphical download manager. It supports both HTTP(S) and FTP protocols and has nice graphical user interface, though some actions can also be performed using the command line.

   Among others, its key features include proxy and SOCKS5 support, recursive downloading, wildcard matching, download scheduler, multiple download queues and more…

   **Install d4x in Ubuntu**

   ```
   sudo aptitude install d4x
   ```
4. **Gwget** (frontend to wget) - it’s a download manager for the Gnome Desktop. The main features are:
   -Resume: By default, gwget tries to continue any download.
   -Notification: Gwget tries to use the Gnome notification area support, if available. You can close the main window and gwget runs in the background.
   -Recursivity: Gwget detects when you put a html, php, asp or a web page dir in the url to download, and ask you to only download certain files (multimedia, only the index, and so on).

   - Drag & Drop: You can d&d a url to the main gwget window or the notification area icon to add a new download.Firefox

   **Install GwGet in Ubuntu**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gwget
   ```
5. **wxDownload**  - wxDownload Fast (also known as wxDFast) is an open source download manager. It is multi-platform and builds on Windows(2k,XP), Linux and Mac OS X(binary still not available). Besides that, it is a multi-threaded download manager. This means that it can split a file into several pieces and download the pieces simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Aria2, supports all functions you can imagine.

Multi-Connection Download

aria2 can download a file from multiple sources/protocols and tries to utilize your maximum download bandwidth. Really speeds up your download experience.
Lightweight

aria2 doesn't require much memory and CPU time. The physical memory usage is typically 4MiB (normal HTTP/FTP downloads) to 9MiB (BitTorrent downloads). CPU usage in BitTorrent with download speed of 2.8MiB/sec is around 6%.
[source and download](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: mention about Aria2 , i mean what it can do and its features. Improve your answers with these things .

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/download/index). It is really great download manager with the following features:

- Platform independent. (Windows, Linux, Mac, ..)
- Runs on Java 1.5 or higher
- Complete Open-Source (GPL)
- Download several files at once
- Download with multiple connections
- JD has an own powerful OCR module
- Automatic extractor (including password list search) (Rar archives)
- Theme Support
- Multilingual
- About 110 hoster and over 300 decrypt plug-ins
- Reconnect with JDLiveHeaderScripts: (1400 router supported)
- Webupdate
- Integrated package manager for additional modules (eg. Webinterface, Shutdown)

You can also try out `uGet` which is already in the official repos.

Install it by opening the Ubuntu Software Center and search the keyword 'uget' or 
if you prefer the command line, `sudo apt-get install uget`