# Need software like 'Internet Download Manager'

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone recommend a download manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager)

Is there any software in Ubuntu like "[Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/)" that downloads audio, video, documents, and software with enhanced speed as it does in Windows? DownloadHelper  helps us download audio and video in Linux, but it is far more basic in comparion to 'IDM'. Is there any solution to this?