# how do i install Internet Download Manager on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: download-speed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need software like 'Internet Download Manager'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54837/need-software-like-internet-download-manager)

I want to install an internet download manager which integrates with my browsers and download at lightning fast speed; I have used uget but the speed isn't satisfactory.