# Download manager for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone recommend a download manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager)

Is there any good download manager for Ubuntu which supports the following?

- Download online streaming video/audio
- scheduling
- grab links from the website
- integration for chrome (one click download like IDM)