# Recommendations for a file-sharing website download manager

Tags: software-recommendation, downloaders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download manager for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79290/download-manager-for-ubuntu)

I am in a need of a better download manager badly.

Can any one Please tell me the name of a download manager which can download from **any file sharing site**

By file sharing site I mean rapidshare.com,hotfile.com, megaupload.com, megashare.com etc.

Now,wget can't download a file from rapidshare.

I was advised to use Steadyflow; but it was buggy. There is a dl manager like Freerapid or something; but that doesn't support other sites.

Someone said me to use Jdownloader; But it loses CONNECTION now and then and then I had to manually reconnect the connection; SO i discarded that. So far i google, i got PLOSHARE pretty useful; but it also doesn't support all the sites above.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could anyone please show me the process to install the latest version of plowshare? (for now)

p.s. @asymptotically, Don't worry, bro. I was & am very normal.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/plowshare/wiki/Readme

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Steadyflow. It's ridiculously light, and can be integrated into both Firefox and Chrome using FlashGot and Chromeflow respectively, so if you use both browsers, you still have a single, comprehensive download history. To install,

```
sudo apt-get install steadyflow
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already use steadyflow; sometimes it shows finished while half downloaded.