# What downloaders are available for downloading large (over 1 GB) files part by part?

Tags: software-recommendation, downloaders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone recommend a download manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager)

I have tried several downloaders but none of them work for large files (over 1 GB) - the problem is I have only 30 KBPS Connection and therefore I need to download a file (Over 1GB) part by part.

I want a perfect alternative of Orbit Downloader or Internet Download Manager of Windows.

Which downloader would you recommend:

1. Jdownloader
2. MultiGet
3. FatRat