# How heavy is wine on my system?

Tags: wine, system, downloaders

I am looking to use a good download manager on ubuntu 12.04 I have tried some such as [MultiGet](http://multiget.sourceforge.net/) etc but really none of the in my view compare up to [Orbit Downloader](http://www.orbitdownloader.com/) which works perfectly under wine.

I want my download manager to always be running (I download a lot) so I am concerned as to how much resources wine actually uses?

Comment: Why not consider available option as [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/129854/what-downloaders-are-available-for-downloading-large-over-1-gb-files-part-by-p) before switching to wine for such options

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wine is not really any more intensive that a normal application, unless there is some memory leak bottleneck in the application you are running.

I don't have any arbitrary numbers for you, but in my experience, Wine is very light (in recent versions) in terms of CPU and memory usage, which is largely due to the fact that Wine is a compatibility layer and not an emulator. What this means then is that applications running on Wine don't need any kind of "translation" or emulation unless of course you are running a Direct 3D game (Direct 3D calls are translated into Open GL counterparts first).

Comment: Are you sure DirectX deserves to be singled out? I mean, is the situation different than for any other Win API - in the end, what wine does is translating Win API calls to access filesystem, draw a window, play a sound etc. into their counterparts in Linux.

Comment: @Sergey: yes and no. The way it works with Direct X is different, as it's not just a matter of touching two ends, so to speak.

Comment: DirectX needs to be translated into more than just OpenGL though, since DirectX is more than Direct3D.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: oh yeah my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you give **uGet** a try. - http://ugetdm.com

WINE is not as resource intensive as you might think but it would certainly be more intensive than running a native app as you will be running two different applications essentially, WINE & Orbit.

uGet is a very powerful yet light in resources native Linux & Ubuntu download manager. uGet also will integrate into Firefox and Chrome making it faster and easier to use.

Disclaimer: I am on the project team for uGet, so might be a bit biased.

Comment: UGet seems good, just one gripe... the icon looks horrible in unity on a dark theme! too big! but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yea I agree about the icon...it would look much MUCH better with the monochrome look in the panel which I have made the icons. I am working with the developer now to add it to the next update.

 **New Icon Preview: [link](http://uget.visuex.com/images/stories/blog/uget-ambiance-icon-preview.png)**

Answer (score 1):

Give Internet Download Manager (IDM) a try. I think its the best and you can install it in wine. You can download it from torrent because it's a paid software.

P.S.- I have installed it on my system and works fine.