# How to make Fatrat run in Lubuntu in spite of being a QT application?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, downloaders, fatrat

I have installed [Fatrat](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fatrat/) in Lubuntu/LXDE and it would not initiate.

--- I have it in the menu, even added the rat to the launch bar, trying to run it in grun, it would not start, just the processor seems to work 3 seconds and then nothing. - Runing `fatrat -f` in terminal gives:

> fatrat: symbol lookup error: fatrat: undefined symbol:
>   _ZN10libtorrent7sessionC1ERKNS_11fingerprintEii

---

(A description of the app [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/170356/47206))

Is it because Fatrat is  based on QT library?

How could I make it work in Lubuntu?

Comment: I think it refers to a problem with the libtorrent library.

Comment: what's libtorrent? should i uninstall it? i've  seen it in synaptic . do i need it to use my default qbittorent?

Comment: Could you post the output of `apt-cache policy libtorrent-rasterbar6 fatrat`?

Comment: `libtorrent-rasterbar6:
  Installed: 0.16.1+svn.r7147-0ubuntu1~oneiric
  Candidate: 0.16.1+svn.r7147-0ubuntu1~oneiric
  Version table:
 *** 0.16.1+svn.r7147-0ubuntu1~oneiric 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.15.10-1 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
fatrat:
  Installed: 1.1.3-3
  Candidate: 1.1.3-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.3-3 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`

Comment: Hmmm... Some how you have a newer version of libtorrent-rasterbar6 than is actually in the Ubuntu repositories. You should re-install it.

Comment: reinstalled  libtorrent-rasterbar6 (and fatrat, qbittorrent etc) - now it works. could you paste it as answer?

Comment: @andrewsomething . i would add your comment as answer. if you object to that fact, just add your parallel answer and i will delete mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer is in fact [andrewsomething](https://askubuntu.com/users/570/andrewsomething)'s comment that i post here as answer:

> a newer version of `libtorrent-rasterbar6`  is actually in the Ubuntu
>   repositories. So, the solution is to re-install it.