# I want an alternative program for IDM

Tags: default-programs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone recommend a download manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager)

I want an alternative program for IDM ( internet download manager ) on ubuntu ??
or how can I setup idm on ubuntu ??

i want A detailed explanation ,please!

Comment: There is a better alternative for IDM: http://askubuntu.com/questions/259228/alternative-to-internet-download-manager-6-x-x-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

[uGet](http://uget.visuex.com/) seems to be [in vogue](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/uget-download-manager-110-released-with.html) at the moment.

From the website:

> Features:
>
> - Free (as in freedom , also free of charge ) and Open Source.
> - Simple , easy-to-use and lightweight .
> - Support resume download , so if your connction lost you don’t need to start from first .
> - Classify downloads , and every category has independent configuration and queue .
> - Queue download .
> - Integrate with Firefox through Flashgot plugin .
> - Monitoring clipboard .
> - Import downloads from HTML file .
> - Batch download , you can download many files has same arrange , like file_1 file_2 …. file_20 , you don’t need to add all links , just
>     one link and changeable character .
> - Can be used from command line .

[image: uGet Home Screen]

You can download it from [here](http://uget.visuex.com/downloads)