# Background Intelligent Transfer Service in ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows

How to use [Background Intelligent Transfer Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) (BITS) in ubuntu ?

thanks

Comment: It is a service related to windows, I don't think you can use it with ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Background Intelligent Transfer Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) is a proprietary solution developed by Microsoft for Windows only. It is not meant to be used or useful in a non-Windows OS.

For Ubuntu we may change the process priority of our download process, or we may use a [Download Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager) of our taste to shape network usage.