# which download manager is FASTER?

Tags: downloads, jdownloader, downloaders

Its a while now Im using linux (Lubuntu). Since the very beginning days DownThemAll was my only download manager here (maybe because i didnt find anything better). now just wanted to know is there any better and FASTER download manager out there for linux? I mean FASTER (its the most important aspect for me)

i heard things about FatRat, JDownloader, Prozgui. but which one is the fastest?

FlareGet is also good, but its not open-souce (in case of malware i never use closed-source)

Comment: This is a very subjective question, and I don't think it can be answered properly. Please see this [question where download managers are discussed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JDownloader. Startup time is not good, but overall performance and GUI is very good. From my perspective, the most important "features" are:

- heavily maintained/updated (all the plugins/addons, new features)
- stable
- integrated with other programs (firefox's flashgot extension)

I've found following related articles:

- http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2010/06/5-fastest-linux-download.html
- http://www.linuxb.in/2012/01/best-8-download-managersaccelerators.html

The first one is nearly all about the command line download managers (nothing for me in this case). On the other hand, I tried "aria2" once.
The second article's winner is prozilla.

So, give both of them a try (JDownloader, prozilla).

Comment: And I agree with the commend above that the answer will be VERY subjective.