# Looking for a download manager

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads

I'm looking a download manager for Ubuntu which allows to resume downloading from the last point if a connection is lost. It should be like download master for windows.

Comment: Uget, I suppose. Also, I used Kget in KDE. Just start Synaptic and search 'download manager', and you will see a lot of alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/q/32850/71679

Comment: Firefox has this functionality.

Comment: @soulsource, really? that's fine.