# What options do I have to increase the download speed of files?

Tags: download-manager

I want to download a 4 GB file which would take approximately 2 hours to finish at its current speed. However, I have a much faster connection capable of downloading it in a couple of minutes at full speed.

What options do I have to increase the download speed of files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone recommend a download manager?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/?src=ss) download manager extension to Firefox. DownThemAll features an advanced accelerator that increases speed up to 4x and it allows you to pause and resume downloads at any time, including resuming interrupted downloads from where they were stopped.

In my experience splitting up the download into 4 parts, which is what DownThemAll does, reduces the download speed to about 5-10% less than the maximum speed that your Internet Service Provider can provide. If you are getting a download rate of 26kbs, then that is not DownThemAll's fault. Axel and aria2 (command line high speed download client) are two download accelerators that you can install from the Ubuntu Software Center if you want to try something else, outside of your web browser.

Comment: Little problem with it- now Firefox lags and dl rate is now 26KB/s. Any other accelators you can suggest?

Comment: In my experience splitting up the download into 4 parts, which is what DownThemAll does, reduces the download speed to about 5-10% less than the maximum speed that your Internet Service Provider can provide. If you are getting a download rate of 26kbs, then that is not DownThemAll's fault. Axel and aria2 (command line high speed download client) are two download accelerators that you can install from the Ubuntu Software Center if you want to try something else, outside of your web browser.

Answer (score 2):

uGet Download Manager is an option you should consider. It is a lightweight, powerful, feature rich native download manager for Linux.

http://ugetdm.com

uGet supports up to 20 Simultaneous connections for downloading, it also supports multiple mirrors (aka sources) so if you have one file hosted on many servers you can use all the servers at once to download one file. uGet also supports Torrents and Metalinks as well as HTTP and FTP links so pretty much everything you need can be downloaded with uGet.

[image: uGet -Main Window]

Answer (score 0):

First, is it available on torrents? If so, you can easily increase downloading up to wirespeed.

Second, try to use "pget" command in the great console client named LFTP.

For example:

```
lftp -e 'pget -n 4 http://url/path/to/file'
```

Comment: I don't trust torrents since I got a terrible virus that bypassed my antivirus.

Comment: Torrents are protected by checksums. The only possibility was that initial file was infected. In this case, there is no difference between direct downloading and getting from torrents.