# problem with uget and flareget.

Tags: download-manager

i am using uget(with aria2 integration) as my default download manager, but currently i have some problem with it. i downloaded a file which is 550mb, after download complete it is showing it is 580mb. anyway after that i try to use flareget, but unfortunately if do not allow download for a single file more then 2 segments. it actually slow my download speed a lot. guys can you provide me a Internet download manager which have a graphical interface like  flareget, or any other download manager which allow multiple segments for files.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/can-someone-recommend-a-download-manager

Comment: buy flareget pro version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uGet is Free and allows up to 20 connections per download.

uGet doesn't add any extra content, it could simply be a mislabeling of the file from wherever you downloaded it from.