# download manager alternative with IDM function

Tags: downloads, idm

Can someone suggest me a download manager with IDM function?
I would like download manager with IDM function like :

1. I am seeking a download manager which is able to help me to download not only in Youtube

   [image: see image]
2. Everytime we are going to download a file, it will pop out a download prompt asking whether we are going to download the file and where we gonna keep the file

   [image]

I would like to apologize for being a noob, but i really hope someone can solve my problem here.. thanks very much

**Note** : I have install Xtreme Download Manager, but I don't get it how to use it as everytime I want to download, XDM never prompt a download option and sometime, Youtube link just not working.. I have just migrated from Windows to Ubuntu 15.04 for the first time in my life..

Comment: possible duplicate of [What download managers are available for Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32850/what-download-managers-are-available-for-ubuntu) Loads of them here for you to try, one should meet your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Latest update:

- Flashgot [not supported](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?t=26260) on [firefox quantum](https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?t=24979) onwards.

I think the best alternative to IDM on linux is [FlareGet](http://flareget.com/), but u'll have to buy the full version to get the full experience , if u want to stick to free software, you can use [uget](http://ugetdm.com/), it's free, it's powerful, and u can use [Flashgot](https://flashgot.net/) integration to make it intercept all the downloads from Firefox, you can even download youtube videos, just like with idm.

Comment: do those apps support downloading video like IDM do?

Comment: Yes, use Flashgot along with Uget, you will be able to download any video, and even choose the quality.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. i will try it.. hope it is simple like IDM so noob like me can use it easily.. thanks

Comment: You are welcome, If you face any problem you can post a question on how to setup everything, i will be glad to help, i use it everyday.