# How to uninstall flareGet?

Tags: download-manager, flareget

I installed this stupid downloader **flareGet** as I am not satisfied with it so I would like to uninstall it up?

And, can anybody suggest me a **downloader** as quick as easy as **IDM** on **Windows**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed `flareget` from [here](http://flareget.com/download) using the DEB package, you have to run

```
sudo apt-get remove flareget
```

Other download managers: [What download managers are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/32850/367165)

Answer (score 0):

**Xtreme Download Manager (XDMAN)**

- List item

  - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get install xdman

**Optional, to remove xdman, do:**

- sudo apt-get remove xdman

This one is the best (Xtreme Download Manager (XDMAN))